# Complex filtergraph

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is what I am trying to accomplish in one FFmpeg process:

- A. Take in 3 inputs
- B. Overlay input 1 over input 0 (input 1 has an alpha channel)
- C. Take the result of step B and concatenate input 3 at the end

Reading up on the documentation I was able to accomplish B and C independently, but when I try chaining them together into a complex filter I can accomplish overlaying input 0-1 but the concatenation does not seem to work.

What it does is just freezing frame on the end of the overlaid clip, for the duration of input 3. In other words the output file has the correct duration, but instead of seeing input 3 at the end I just get a frozen frame at the end of input 2. Hopefully that is clear...

Here is the command I am using:

```
-loop 1 -r 29.97 -i input0.png -r 29.97 -i input1_%04d.png -i input2.mov \
    -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=shortest=1;[1][2]concat=n=2:v=1" 
     output.mov
```

I believe I am close enough, so hopefully this is just a simple tweak!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a pad with a label to the result of the overlay and feed that to concat. The `[1]` fed to concat refers to the source frames of the image sequence. And since the overlay result isn't labelled. It is included as the first output stream, with the wrong concat result being the 2nd.

Use

```
-loop 1 -framerate 30000/1001 -i input0.png
        -framerate 30000/1001 -i input1_%04d.png
                              -i input2.mov
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=shortest=1[ovl];[ovl][2]concat=n=2:v=1"
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 output.mov
```

See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description and  http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection

Comment: Thanks a bunch Gyan, this is just what I needed.

Comment: @Spencer You need to think of `[0]` and `[1]` as variables, which *must* be sent to another variable if you run a filter on them then want to run further filters on the result. Gyan named that variable `[ov1]`. FFmpeg needs to be able to reference the output of any used filter if you want to run other filters on it, otherwise it will try to send it directly into the output file.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia thanks, makes sense